# Kendo Scheduler keep calendar as open

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler, kendo-datepicker

i have kendo-scheduler and what i want is i want to keep the calendar as open when scheduler get loaded.

[image]

if i click on calendar button then it will open the calendar control but i don't want to click on any button to open the date picker.it should get open when scheduler get loaded.

[image]

please suggest me what to do to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this thing by using below code snippet.

```
<script>
 var isSchedulerLoadFirstTime;
        function scheduler_dataBound(e) {
            //condition to open calender on initial load only
            if (isSchedulerLoadFirstTime != false) { 
                // This code line will open calender in schduler
                $(".k-nav-current").trigger('click'); 
                isSchedulerLoadFirstTime = false;
            }
        }

        $(function () {
            $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
                dataBound: scheduler_dataBound,
            ......
            ......
            });
</script>
```

Let me know if any concern.